# How to move Table View section down in the User Interface

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview

I am building a simple app in Xcode, started from an empty project template. I added a storyboard file on which I dropped a TableViewController, when I connect the view to a data source in code to display the data. It all worked correctly except that the top of the Table view section is overlays into the status bar section. I want to move it down so that there is space (at least 8pts) between the status bar and the Table View section. Here is an image to show what I'm facing[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to move down the tableView as per your UI, first get the status bar height by using :

```
 NSLog(@"%f",[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height);
```

and then move down your table view as per your status bar height which is 20 :

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20,0,0,0)];
```

Answer (score 0):

just add following line in your project.

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
```

Comment: where appropriately should i put this code? Is it inside the viewDidLoad method?